# Java - Multiple constructors with same arguments

Tags: java, constructor, arguments

I need to create multiple constructors with same arguments so that I can call these from my DAO class for populating different drop down values

```
public static Employee empType(String empCode, String empType) {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp .empCode= empCode;
    emp .empType= empType;
    return emp ;
}

 public static Employee empDept(String deptCode, String deptName) {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp .deptCode= deptCode;
    emp .deptName= deptName;
    return emp ;
}
```

When I am referencing from DAO class, how can I refer to these constructors?

E.g.

```
private static Employee myList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    return new <what should be here>((resultSet.getString("DB_NAME1")), 
                      (resultSet.getString("DB_NAME2")));
}
```

Comment: Even I had same type of requirements, but I don't think it is possible, since Java distinguishes overloaded method based on arguments of the methods, and if two constructor has same type of arguments, this won't work. But experts need to shed their opinion.

Comment: Are they really Constructors? Infact, they are not even overloaded methods!

Comment: No, they are not constructors. They are factory functions.

Comment: @R.J you correct i thing they are two separate static methods

Comment: I'm amazed seeing so many responses, all talking about multiple constructors, when there aren't any in the code!

Comment: you could just use `return empType(str1, str2);` to achieve whatever you want!

Comment: Those static methods are sometimes called [Named Constructors](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cant.
Also, these functions aren't constructors. And how do you want to decide which "constructor" to call???

You can merge both functions:

```
public static Employee createEmp(String empCode, String empType, String deptName) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp .empCode= empCode;
    emp .empType= empType;
    emp .deptName= deptName;
    return emp ;
}
```

And use `null` as the unneeded argument.

Comment: baraky null approach would be useful and better. Thanks

Comment: hi, 
could you give an example of using null as unneeded argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You cannot Create multiple constructors/methods with the same name and same arguments

What you can do is change your implementation, and those are not Contructors.

You can follow what Baraky did, you can also use this(create a boolean flag,or an int value flag)

```
public Employee empType(String val1, String val2, int type) {

     Employee emp = new Employee();

    if(type == 1){
          emp .empCode= val1;
          emp .empType= val2;
    }else if(type ==2){
          emp.deptCode= val1;
          emp .deptName= val2;
     }
    return emp ;
}
```

Comment: if the type would be an enum the code would be more readable.

Comment: He can also do that, or using a boolean. just pointing out that there  are other approaches he or she can do.

Comment: In java constructor can not be static and it can not return any value.here i think you are just overloading a function.

Answer (score 4):

From the [article](http://davin.50webs.com/research/2008/mcwtsa.html):

> In Java you cannot have multiple methods (including constructors) with
>   the same arguments. To get around this limitation you need to use
>   static methods with different names that serve the client code as
>   constructors. In the code that follows the static methods `ctorApple`,
>   `ctorBanana` and `ctorCarrot` internally call the private constructor
>   `Foo()` and serve in the role of multiple constructors with the same
>   arguments. The prefix ctor is intended to remind the client that these
>   methods serve in the role of constructors.

```
class Foo
{
   private Foo()
   {
     // ...
   }
   public static Foo ctorApple(/* parameters */)
   {
       Foo f = new Foo();
       // set properties here using parameters
       return f;
   }
   public static Foo ctorBanana(/* parameters */)
   {
       Foo f = new Foo();
       // set properties here using parameters
       return f;
   }
   public static Foo ctorCarrot(/* parameters */)
   {
       Foo f = new Foo();
       // set properties here using parameters
       return f;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must have multiple constructors you could add a dummy parameter like this.

```
public static Employee empType(String empCode, String empType) {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp .empCode= empCode;
    emp .empType= empType;
    return emp ;
}

 public static Employee empDept(String deptCode, String deptName, bool dummy) {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp .deptCode= deptCode;
    emp .deptName= deptName;
    return emp ;
}
```

When doing this it is a minimal performance(veryveryvery small) drop, but if the code is more readable it is worth it :)

Comment: Is this an accepted method for dealing with these kind of situations?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think multiple constructor with same arguments (data type) are allowed by java.

Comment: overloaded methods?! As far as I know, overloaded methods, have the **SAME NAME**.

Answer (score 1):

If you need flexible creation of objects, check out the `Builder` pattern. In your case however, I don't see why it shouldn't work just to have one constructor with all your parameters. Just fetch all the properties from the resultSet, and if they're null, they'll just not be set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have TWO same constructor with same parameter meaning but different effect, you can try to clutch them into one:

```
public Name(Type parameter, boolean type) {
    if(type) {

    }else {

    }
}
```

If you have 2+ same constructor then use `int type` and `switch`. Just suggestion.

EDIT: `types` in this case should be defined by `enum` for easier code grasp.

Answer (score 1):

If using a different set of parameters for the constructor changes the behavior how it acts, I would suggest extending or using composition to create a new class with the new set of parameters.

That will also adhere to OPEN/CLOSE pricipal.